# Codeigniter count registered visitors

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to implement registered visitors.
Each time a visitor sees my site I increment plus 1 but it seems not working.
Increment is plus 3 I don't know why.

I added the function to MY_Controller in core folder to run in all controllers.

Here is the code added to MY_Controller:

```
public function __construct()
{   
    parent::__construct();     
    $this->onlineusers_lib->increnement_test();
}
```

library:

```
public function increnement_test()
{
     $user_data = $this->CI->user_lib->get_user($user_id);
     $visit = $user_data->count_site_visit+1;
     $data = array('last_activity'    => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 
                   'count_site_visit' => $visit
                  );
     $this->CI->users_model->update_user($user_id, $data);
}
```

-Thanks

Comment: You don't need get previous value to incrementing, just use SQL query. Something like this: `UPDATE tb_name SET count_site_visit=count_site_visit+1 WHERE user_id=$user_id`

Comment: I tried that too but I get always plus 3.

Comment: same issue.... it seems the function is executed several time

Comment: I think the problem is with the workflow. The constructor will called everytime when you call any function.

Comment: Wait a second. Maybe I am miss understanding. Is the value incrementing with 3 each time or the function called 3 times?

Comment: The value is incremented with 3 each time. I think it's because the function is called 3 times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179240/discussion-between-mappy-lord-and-nur-muhammad).

Comment: @MappyLord are you using `log_message` in any part of the code to debug this? Are you sure no more activity in your server that could trigger the `update_user` more than 1 times? for what its worth, i tried to add `__construct` declaration in a random controller, and it fired only once.